# Could not load type 'System.UI.Page' Configuration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm receiving this error trying to show an ASP.NET web forms page in a folder in an ASP.NET MVC application. Am I missing an assembly reference or package?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.UI.Page'.

Source Error:


Line 324:        </mobileControls>
Line 325:
Line 326:        <pages pageBaseType="System.UI.Page" userControlBaseType="System.UI.UserControl">
Line 327:            <namespaces>
Line 328:                <add namespace="System" />


Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config    Line: 326

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) is not in `System.UI`. It's in `System.Web.UI` namespace, in the `System.Web` assembly. You should have `System.Web` referenced by default, so just fix the fully qualified name in your `web.config`. Same thing goes for `UserControl` class.

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.UI.Page" userControlBaseType="System.Web.UI.UserControl">
```

Comment: This is actually coming from the (unmodified) web.config in the Framework directory:

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config    Line: 326

Comment: In my (unmodified) version of that file, the `pageBaseType` and `userControlBaseType` attributes aren't even present. I think you should modify them as I described or remove them. My best guess is *someone* modified your file.

Comment: I made the change and this fixed it. I guess I have a follow-up question: What could have modified the file? Maybe it's impossible to know. Anyway, thanks and credit to you mason.

Comment: Probably some person modified it. Or perhaps there was a bug in the .NET installer. Hard to say.